# Windows.Activate - Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range - When using wildcard "*"

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to build a macro that will activate a window.  And the file name updates daily with the current date.  My issue seems to arise when I try to incorporate the wildcard "*".  I receive a

> Run-time error '9'.

And I do not have an error if I enter the file name exactly.

I have tried several variations.  Every discussion that I've found leads me to believe it should work.  Can anyone help me work this out?

File Name:  01032020_ACES Pipeline Mgmnt Tracking Report.xlsb

```
Sub WindowActivate()

Windows("*" & "_ACES Pipeline Mgmnt Tracking Report.xlsb").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not use wild card while activating any window in VBA
but you can try something like....

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*_ACES Pipeline Mgmnt Tracking Report.xlsb" Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit for
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works for me.
But that still leaves me with a question... Why can't it be used in this situation?  Is there a topic that I should read up on that you can point me toward?  I'm extremely new to this so any information is much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: for your clarification... imagine having two windows with name "Test123.xlsx" and "123.xlsx"; now if you give wild card for window activation like this "*123.xlsx" it will be confusing which window to activate as both windows will be valid for that criteria